# does core motion activity is related to core location

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, core-motion

how core motion activity will works on foreground, background and when app was terminated by user.... how it was related to location manager

actually am tracking user location foreground, background and while app terminated also. so my issue is am getting location update while in foreground and background. but after terminating app am not getting any location update until i again re-enable the location services.. this an one issue

one more is i need to track users activity also this was also same when app was in foreground, background working fine. but after terminate activity is not updating until again i re-enable(switch off and on location) location services.

is their any way to fix this issues. please help me

thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got what was exactly going on with core-motion-activity
when we killed app app will go on dead state(that means it wont execute any code). to wake up app we need to use background modes it will work even after app killed..

so here am using location services on background to wake up app and get core motion activities updates

Comment: Hey, can you explain a little bit more as to how did you invoke the app from terminated state? Once it’s terminated how can it go to background mode again? Would really appreciate a minimal code example